# How to get a currently active Activity?

Tags: android, testing

I'm doing some tests using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>` class. Sometimes I launch new `Activities` within my test so `getActivity().finish()` isn't working to close current `Activity` which prevents further tests execution. Is there a way to get a reference to currently opened activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/)? It has some nice helpers for doing stuff like this, as well as a very convenient cleanup method that closes all the activities you might have opened during a test:

```
solo.finishOpenedActivities();
```

With it you can also do stuff like:

```
solo.goBack();
solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected RunModeActivity", RunModeActivity.class);
```

Worth taking a look.

Comment: Yes, I did. The `solo.finishOpenedActivities()` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Update: I did notice the `solo.finishOpenedActivities()` just hide the soft keyboard (which is active) and if I call it again - everything is just fine. The question is - why it just hides the keyboard? Oo